Changing the settings of a plugin installed on a multisite
I installed a plugin on 100 of WordPress multisite sites.
How can I change the settings of this plugin in a group and at once?
I don't mean installing and updating the plugin. I want to change the plugin settings and options

Based on how plugin implemnted you can:

Multisite Network Admin Interface:
If the plugin settings are network-wide settings, you can access and modify them through the Network Admin interface.

Plugin Configuration File:
If the plugin you're using supports config file, you can make changes to the configuration file and upload it to all the sites.

Custom Script or Plugin:
If the plugin doesn't provide built-in support for network-wide settings or configuration files, you need to a custom plugin that modifies the settings of the target plugin across all sites in the network. This plugin would need to iterate through each site in the network and update the plugin settings programmatically.

Third-Party Management Tools:
Use third-party management tools and plugins (MainWP, WP Multisite Synchronize, WP Ultimo, etc) for managing multisite installations.


